# What is the formula to get nifty it sectorial index price

Tags: google-finance

Want sector data formulas like cnxpharma,cnxit,cnxfmcg

=Googlefinance("NSE:CNXIT","price").  Not working try this can any one suggest nse sector index price formula.........Pharma index,it index,FMCG index,auto index data in Google sheets already track nifty_50,nifty_bank prices..like=googlefinance("nse:nifty_50","price") working well but how to get other sectors data

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_IT","price")
```